# Specify the event you want

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, events, triggers

I have lots of checkboxes. Most of them have one class(class a or class b) but some of them have both classes.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="a b">
```

I have the same jquery event (change) for both of these classes.

```
$('.a').change(function(e){ // whatever });
$('.b').change(function(e){ // whatever });
```

In my code I have to trigger the event "change" from the input in a .each(). It means there can be checkboxes of any case stated above.

```
$(this).trigger('change');
```

My problem is that when I trigger it from a checkbox which has both classes, it triggers the 2 distinct event (and it's logic).
But I just want to trigger the chosen change event of one class.

Is there a way to specify this ?

Comment: if you only want trigger event of class a, why you add class b to it?

Comment: what do you want from `class='a b'` checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

Why not specify like this?

```
$('.a:not(".a.b")').change(function(){
//only a
});

$('.a.b').change(function(){
//both
});

$('.b:not(".a.b")').change(function(){
//only b    
});
```

Comment: what to trigger when click in the `class="a b"`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your problem by filtering our the elements that expose both classes. For instance, only register the handler for class `b` if the element doesn't also expose class `a`:

```
$(".a").change(function(e) { /* whatever */ });
$(".b:not(.a)").change(function(e) { /* whatever */ });
```